# ssh config generic vs specific the title meets quality standards

Tags: ssh

I have .ssh/config starting with

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%C
ControlPersist 24h
ForwardAgent yes
ServerAliveInterval 60
AddressFamily inet
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

and end with

```
Host ssh.example.com
Hostname ssh.real.example.com
Port 32222
StrictHostKeyChecking No
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
ControlMaster No
ControlPath none
```

but it is still using ControlMaster and it is a huge problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are host configurations in the SSH config merged?](https://superuser.com/questions/1456255/are-host-configurations-in-the-ssh-config-merged)

Comment: In short: "For each directive, the *first* relevant occurrence in the `ssh_config` is used".

Comment: Additionally from [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1800426/432690): 'Don't think of `Host`/`Match` as separate "sections", in general – think of it as a single large config where some settings are *filtered*'. Follow these rules and you will be able to parse the config like `ssh` does.